# Testing api with Guzzle getting 403

Tags: php, rest, symfony, guzzle6

I'm coding an api with symfony 4, so in order to test it I installed Guzzle to make some requests.
I have a local web server (the very same from php - or for what matters the one you run with symfony's console).

My code is the one below:

```
<?php

require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request;

$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client([
    'base_uri' => 'http://127.0.0.1:8000',
    'http_errors' => false,
]);

$response = $client->get('/');

echo $response->getStatusCode();    // --> 403
```

Or if I comment the line with 'http_errors' => false, I get:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException: Client error: `GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/` resulted in a `403 Forbidden` response:
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv (truncated...)
 in D:\Work\Programming\SIGMET\2.0\sigmet_2.0\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Exception\RequestException.php:113
Stack trace:
#0 D:\Work\Programming\SIGMET\2.0\sigmet_2.0\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Middleware.php(66): GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException::create(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response))
#1 D:\Work\Programming\SIGMET\2.0\sigmet_2.0\vendor\guzzlehttp\promises\src\Promise.php(203): GuzzleHttp\Middleware::GuzzleHttp\{closure}(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response))
#2 D:\Work\Programming\SIGMET\2.0\sigmet_2.0\vendor\guzzlehttp\promises\src\Promise.php(156): GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise::callHandler(1, Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response), Array)
#3 D:\Work\Programming\SIGMET\2.0\sigmet_2.0\vendor\guzzlehttp\promises\src\Ta in D:\Work\Programming\SIGMET\2.0\sigmet_2.0\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Exception\RequestException.php on line 113
```

What can it be?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you go to http://127.0.0.1:8000 in your browser, what do you see? Your error code seems to suggest that URL is forbidden access.

Comment: You need better error handling. If you write an API the return value should be json (or whatever) in any case. Even in error case.

Comment: I can browse it normally

Comment: The problem is @Mruf that I can't get the response from my server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem was on enviroment variables defining proxy settings